# Why is the GAE python SDK using the system's python while in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I am inside a virtualenv. I have installed the GAE python SDK following [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python). As per the instructions, the SDK is not directly on the virtualenv, but is in the path.

I have installed some (non-vendored, that is, in the virtualenv) packages and I am starting the GAE development server:

```
» dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

But this crashes when processing a request with:

```
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/foo/bar/appengine-django-skeleton/mysite/settings.py", line 105, in <module>
    import dj_database_url
ImportError: No module named dj_database_url
```

What I have already verified:

- the virtualenv is active
- the package is installed in the virtualenv
- the active python is the one in the virtualenv
- the package can be imported when on the python shell
- `dev_appserver.py` has on the first line `#!/usr/bin/env python`, which should be telling the system to use the active python (the one from the virtualenv!)

Why is `/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py` being used at all? This does not belong to the active python (the one on the virtualenv)!

### EDIT

There is [a project](https://github.com/peterhudec/gae_installer) to install the sdk on a virtualenv, but it's outdated. Is there a more recent method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [dizballanze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34912565/2295256), I instead prefer to keep everything installed in my `virtualenv` and then symlink my `virtualenv's site packages` to the `lib` folder with something similar to:

```
ln -s env/lib/python2.7/site-packages lib
```

which results in a folder whereby my `devappserver` uses the `virtualenv`'s packages

```
├── env
├── lib -> env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

You can read more of my approach at https://www.jeffgodwyll.com/posts/2015/google-appegine-vendoring-done-right/

**EDIT**

App engine uploads all files in the project directory. To prevent app engine from uploading the entire virtualenv let it through the `skip files` section of your `app.yaml`:

```
skip_files:
- ^env$  # virtual environment's folder
```

Comment: Thanks, but the package I am installing in the virtualenv is a package which *must not* be vendored. It is just needed when developing on the localhost, but not needed in gae. That's why I just install in the virtualenv (and not in the vendor directory), but the `dev_appserver.py` does not find it.

Comment: And a general question: are you tracking the virtualenv in your repo? To deploy to gae you need to have the vendored libraries committed to your repo ...

Comment: If it must not be vendored as it's not needed in production, you can just skip both the `virtualenv` and the `lib` folder. That way they aren't tracked

Comment: With this approach, I'm tracking just the virtualenv's site packages and not the entire virtualenv

Comment: Not sure how you could have a package required for dev but not for production (may be a profiler) in which case include the module in a standard lib dir (as per all other recommendations for 3rd party libs) and use skip files so it doesn't get deployed.

Comment: ok, I see. I usually ignore the whole virtualenv. Not sure how to ignore a directory but track a specific subdirectory. I'll need to check the git docs

Comment: @TimHoffman: in this case I am hardcoding the database settings in my settings.py for the gae environment, but I am using dj_database_url to set up the database settings in the localhost.

Comment: @gonvaled you don't need to track any subdirectory, ignore the entire env and just keep a requirements file and you should be ok across setups

Comment: Mmmm. As far as I understand, gae does not install requirements (as opposed to Heroku, for example): they need to be installed on the repo and pushed with the deploy. So they need to be tracked.

Comment: An alternative approach whould be to check if your in DEV in app_config when the instance starts, if so explicitly load settings,  If not don't do it.  You can also ignore your local settings so they are not deployed.  Keeps things very simple,

Answer (score 1):

GAE does not currently support `virtualenv`. To use packages you could:

- write a list of needed packages [supported by GAE runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#runtime-libraries) in `app.yaml`
- install third-party packages to `lib/` directory (pure python packages only) and add these code to `appengine_config.py`:

  ```
  from google.appengine.ext import vendor

  # Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
  vendor.add('lib')
  ```

Read more in [GAE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

Comment: Thanks, but the package I am installing in the virtualenv is a package which *must not* be vendored. It is just needed when developing on the localhost, but not needed in gae. That's why I just install in the virtualenv (and not in the vendor directory), but the `dev_appserver.py` does not find it.

Comment: BTW: the link you provide is giving details on third party libraries *when running on gae*. Is there any documentation on how to use the GAE python  SDK during development, on the localhost?

Comment: And also: nowhere I can find a statement saying that gae does not support virtualenv (on the localhost).

Comment: It doesn't.  any library that is not part of the runtime or directly supported lirbraries must be in your code base.  Remember the dev server is emulating the production sandbox.  It will not look for libraries/files outside of your project structure.  What applies to the production environment applies to production - except you need to provide the supported 3rd party librabries yourself - ie lxml